# How to intercept, parse and compile?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, postsharp, castle-dynamicproxy, linfu-dynamicproxy

This is a problem I've been struggling to solve for a while. I need a way to either replace code in the method with a parsed code from the template at compile time (PostSharp comes to mind) or to create a dynamic proxy (Linfu or Castle). So given a source code like this

```
[Template]

private string GetSomething()

{

var template = [%=Customer.Name%]

}
```

I need it to be compiled into this

```
private string GetSomething()

{

MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mStream,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

writer.Write(@"" );

writer.Write(Customer.Name);

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mStream); 

writer.Flush();

mStream.Position = 0; 

return sr.ReadToEnd();

}
```

It is not important what technology is used. I tried with PostSharp's ImplementMethodAspect but got nowhere (due to lack of experience with it). I also looked into Linfu framework. Can somebody suggest some other approach or way to do this, I would really appreciate. My whole project depends on this.

**Assumptions:**

1. Code can appear in any class.
2. Template code will always be annotated with attribute [Template]
3. Template method will always return string.

Parsing of the code from one form to another is already done. Now I just need a way to replace it.

"Beefer" example:

```
  [Test]
        public void can_parse_csharp_code_template3()
        {
            var template = @"<template> [%= GetUsing() %]
    namespace [%= GetModelNamespaceName(.metaPackage) %]
    {
    [%= .visibility.ToString().ToLower() %] class [%= .Name %] : INotifyPropertyChanged [%= If(.IsPersistent, "", PersistenObject"", """") %]
        {
            #region Constructors
            [%= ConstructorTemplate.Create(metaObject).GetParameterlessConstructorCode %]
            #endregion

            #region Attributes

            [%= From attribute In metaObject.attributes _
                Select (AttributeTemplate.Create(attribute).GetSourceCode) %]
            #endregion

            #region Relationships
            [%= From relationship As Relationship In metaObject.relationships _
                Select (RelationshipTemplateFactory.CreateFor(relationship).GetSourceCode()) %]
            #endregion

            #region Methods
            [%= From operation In metaObject.operations _
                Select (MethodTemplate.Create(operation).GetSourceCode) %]
            #endregion

            #region ""INotifyPropertyChanged""
            [%= GetOnPropertyChanged() %]
            #endregion
            }
        }</template>";

            Console.WriteLine(TemplateParser.GetParsedResult(template));

        }
```

Comment: What on earth is the point of doing this in the first place?

Comment: @Matti: That is beyond the point of what is the point. I cannot go into details of why it is needed.

Comment: Your template essentially reduces to `return Customer.Name;` which makes the use of templates somewhat silly. So asking if templates are required at all, is a valid question IMO.

Comment: @dtb: It is just a simple example. Do you need me to post complete template that is 200 lines long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at  [T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" encoding="utf-8" #>

private string GetSomething()
{
    <# Generate("Customer.Name"); #>
}

<#+
private void Generate(string s)
{
    WriteLine(@"MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();");
    // ...
}
#>
```

Comment: @dtb: T4 teplates can appear anywhere in the body of any class?

Comment: @epitka: Yes. You create a `.tt` file which contains your C# code amended with `<#= ... #>` and/or `<# ... #>` directives. The `.tt` is then transformed to a `.cs` file by the *TextTemplatingFileGenerator* custom tool before compilation.

Comment: So VS will generate the file and then compile it and I only need to deploy .dll?

Comment: @epitka: Yes. Visual Studio will run the custom tool for you. The result is an assembly as if you had written the generated C# file by hand.

Answer (score 0):

A tool that can parse C#, pick out attributes, and transform that code any way you'd like, is the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C# Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CSharpFrontEnd.html).

DMS parses your files, builds full abstact syntax trees, and allows you to write custom transformations that can expand a point in the text (what most code generators like T4 do) or more importantly replace any construct (both local and/or distributed across the *set* of files that make up the application) with any other code you might like to generate.

You appear to have some idea about the metalanguage for producing code fragments, e.g.,

```
  From operation In metaObject.operations _ 
            Select (MethodTemplate.Create(operation).GetSourceCode)
```

That metalanguage AFAIK isn't C#.  With DMS, you can define a parser for the metalanguage, and process the meta langauge into trees as the code generator encounters the constructs.  With a small interpreter over such trees, you can convert metalnguage text into generator actions producing the text of interest.

[I'm the CTO behind DMS].

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer the quiestion. I will certainly look into you tool. You are right, it is not c# reflection meta data, but custom meta model that targets model driven development.